# white Background appears when i backpress from placePicker

Tags: android

i am having PlaceActivity which launches PlacePicker but a white background appears after when i backpress from placepicker i think that background is default contentView of that activity.
help me to remove default background from activity.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String lat=getSharedPreferences(Constant.LOCATION,MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getString(Constant.LATITUDE,null);
    if(lat==null){
        PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder=new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
        try {
            startActivityForResult(builder.build(this),PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
            return;
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else {
        String lon=getSharedPreferences(Constant.LOCATION,MODE_PRIVATE)
                .getString(Constant.LONGITUDE,null);
        displayNearbyPlaces(lat,lon);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Place place=PlacePicker.getPlace(this,data);
        LatLng latLng=place.getLatLng();
        displayNearbyPlaces(String.valueOf(latLng.latitude),String.valueOf(latLng.longitude));
    }
}

private void displayNearbyPlaces(String lat,String lon) {

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_places);
    resources=getResources();
    mLat=lat;
    mLong=lon;
    /*Intent intent=getIntent();
    mLat=intent.getStringExtra(Constant.LATITUDE);
    mLong=intent.getStringExtra(Constant.LONGITUDE);*/
    setActionBar(R.id.main_toolbar);
    ViewPager viewPager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    LocationPagerAdapter pagerAdapter=new LocationPagerAdapter(this,getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(viewPager.getAdapter().getCount());
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab);
    tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white));
    tabLayout.setTabTextColors(resources.getColor(R.color.gray),resources.getColor(R.color.white));
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}
```

Comment: Put `setContentView(R.layout.activity_places);` after `super.onCreate(...)`

Comment: i only want to set the "R.layout.activity_places" as contentView if i found somethind in sharedPrefrences() otherwise i want to display PlacePicker

Comment: PlacePicker is a separate activity that's going to start based on your conditions. If your conditions meet, that activity will launch even before your onCreate of this activity is completed. Which means you would never see the UI of this activity. I am not very sure but i think using setContentView the way you have used might be illegal since it can execute after your onCreate has completed and also from onActivityResult which does not run on UI thread.

Comment: see whenever setContentView is called new layout of an Activity is defined it doesn't matter where do you set the contentView of an activity if you dont set the ContentView then it displays the default layout of the activity(white Background)

Comment: What exactly do you wanna see when you press back from the place picker activity ?

Comment: i just want to exit so that no white background appears to user

Comment: Then inside your onActivityResult, put `else { finish(); }`. This will finish your activity

Comment: finish () will exit the activity then after selecting any place from place picker how can i return to onActivityResult method of same Activity.

Comment: @Vikas Sharma see my updated answer. Your activity will finish when you click back on PlacePicker

Comment: I am not able to understand what you want to achieve. When you select a place from your placepicker, you will end up in `if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK)`. If you press back, you will end up in `else {}` of this since the result code will not be qual to RESULT_OK.

Comment: @user1209216's answer is corrrect and should achieve what your question has specified.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any content view set if location is unknown and not stored in shared prefs. Set some content view in `onCreate` in that case. If you click back in PlacePicker, your `displayNearbyPlaces` won't be called.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Place place=PlacePicker.getPlace(this,data);
        LatLng latLng=place.getLatLng();
        displayNearbyPlaces(String.valueOf(latLng.latitude),String.valueOf(latLng.longitude));
    }
else finish();
}
```

Comment: i have not set the contentView if (lat==null) because i only want place picker to be displayed